# PowerPoint fonts not listed under Windows

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I am looking for the real system name of some fonts that exist in PowerPoint so that I can use them programmatically in some other places where I create graphs via Python. In Office (PowerPoint) I can see some pretty fonts like `Avenir Next LT Pro Light` that I want to use. Yet, on Windows 10 when I go to the Fonts in settings, I cannot find any mention of Avenir. Why is that and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fonts - Avenir Next among them - are what Microsoft calls “Cloud fonts” and are (nominally) only available to Office applications. The actual font files are downloaded from the cloud when you first call for them in a document, and then stored in `C:\Users\«your-user-name»\AppData\Local\Microsoft\FontCache\4\CloudFonts\` in a directory matching the font family name against future need.

Note that if you exchange a document using a cloud font with a computer that doesn't have a cloud-enabled version of Office installed, the appearance of the document may change due to unavailability of the font.

Comment: BTW, you can download and install Avenir Next from https://freefontsfamily.com/avenir-next-font-download-free/ and other sites. Before installing, check any font at https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload . As mentioned, if you use an unusual font in a shared document, it might be substituted, unless you *embed* the font.